# Java Protobuf decode

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have many protobuf messages defined , all of them have a common field , (the message definition and the tag number) . now i could get the ByteString of a ProtoBuf message , it could be any of the messages i defined. but now i'm only care about the first field . and i have this field's Message Definition but not the whole message .[image]

I'm designing a proxy server, the router info is set in the first field , and i don't wanna care the detail of the of each request message .

my question is : is there a way to extraxt the first field infomation of a protobuf byteString , if i only have this field definition and the tag num .

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out myself , in case it would be helpful to others , i'll post the answer.

```
        EduExamPackage.QuestionDetailTest.Builder testPb = EduExamPackage.QuestionDetailTest.newBuilder().setQuestion(EduExamPackage.Question.newBuilder().setAid(6666));
        byte[] byteData = testPb.build().toByteArray();
        EduExamPackage.Question question = EduExamPackage.Question.getDefaultInstance();
       for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <10000000 ; j++) {
                try {

                    question = EduExamPackage.Question.PARSER.parseFrom(byteData, i, j);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (question.hasAid()) {
                    System.out.println("found aid ! : " + question.getAid());
                    System.out.println("found !!!  \n  i: "+ i+ " j: "+j);
                    return ;
                }
            }
        }`
```

`found !!!

  i: 2 j: 3`

the result is show that fields are regularly alined . so the commond field at specific tag num could be get in this way .